# Tensorflow Batch Training

Tags: tensorflow

I have a code segment to train a tensorflow model by batches. `getChunk` returns a training data of `BATCH_SIZE` and returns false at the end of file. I expected the log entry to be sequential, e.g if the total dataset size is 10, batch size is 5, I expected the log file to be 1,1,2,2,3,3 and so on. However, the file is mixed and I see orders like 1,2,3,1,3,2 ...What am I doing wrong.

```
for i in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
gen = getLine(TMP_DATA_PATH+"/"+"data_train.txt")
tmp_X, tmp_Y=getChunk(gen)

while tmp_X != False:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: tmp_X, Y: tmp_Y})

    _, acc_train, loss_train = sess.run([pred_softmax, accuracy, loss], feed_dict={X: tmp_X, Y: tmp_Y})

    logEntry(str(i)+" "+str(loss_train)+" "+str(acc_train))
    tmp_X, tmp_Y=getChunk(gen)
```

data_train.txt is a CSV file that contains a sequence of vectors followed by one hot encoded label.

```
[[1,2,3,4],[-1,2,3,4],........[-5,2,3,1]],[0,0,0,1]

def getLine(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as file:
        for i in file:
            yield i.rstrip()

def getChunk(genLine):
    try:
        chunk = [next(genLine) for i in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
        assert(len(chunk)==BATCH_SIZE)
        X=[]
        Y=[]
        for c in chunk:
            y=c[-30:]
            x=c[:-30]

            x_list=eval(x)
            y=eval(y)

            X.append(x_list)
            Y.append(y)

        X = np.asarray(X)
        return X,Y

    except:
        return False,False

def logEntry(TMP_STRING):
    LOG_FILE.write(TMP_STRING)
    LOG_FILE.write("\n")
    LOG_FILE.flush()
    print(TMP_STRING)
```

Comment: What does the content of data_train.txt look like and what are your getLine(), getChunk() and logEntry() functions doing?

Comment: I edited the post with the functions. I think I found the problem. It was cause by another instance of the program writing to the same file. Looks like the code is ok.